# Nginx giving 404 error for WordPress' /wp-admin/ root

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a Symfony2 application running alongside WordPress - mysite.com/blog routes to my `/var/www/mysite/wordpress/` directory and everything else routes to `/var/www/mysite/symfony`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        internal;
    }

    location /blog {
        root /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
        rewrite ^/blog/(.+)$ /$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog)(.+\.php)(.*);
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except the WordPress admin (mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/) gives me a 404 error. Visiting mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php works as expected, so it looks like the `index index.php` line is not working. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Show full config. I don't see `/blog/` part in `/wp-admin/` path, so this location is irrelevant to question.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Sorry, I should clarify that I'm accessing /blog/wp-admin/. I've updated the question.

Comment: Is the wordpress index.php in `/var/www/mysite/wordpress`? Then I think your try_files clause in /blog location block should be `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `alias` instead of `root` directive:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    alias /var/www/mysite/wordpress;
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(?:\/blog)(.+\.php)(.*);
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Valery, but I was actually unable to use alias:
http://serverfault.com/questions/642579/how-can-i-get-around-using-alias-in-nginx
Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jonathan, I've tested solution with latest nginx/wordpress and everything works as expected.

Comment: You're absolutely right - looks like it got patched in the year or so since I posted that question. Thanks for trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the nginx server Configuration.

```
# WordPress single blog rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
#include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and works with "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" in /etc/php.ini (default)

    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
#   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

More about this here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#General_WordPress_rules

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, but this doesn't cover my multi-site setup.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you allege that `/blog/wp-admin/index.php` works, but `/blog/wp-admin/` doesn't, perhaps just conditionally append `index.php`, if need be?

```
+    rewrite ^/blog/wp-admin(/)?$ /wp-admin/index.php break;
     rewrite ^/blog/(.+)$ /$1 break;
```

---

So, what do the logs say in regards to your 404?  I think this might be related to the fact that the [`index`](http://nginx.org/r/index) directive causes "an internal redirect", thus I would not be surprised if your `404` ends up being generated through the `/` instead of the `/blog` `location`.